# Removing a database entry after certain amount of time with Rails

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a webapp which allows you to create a lobby with a link to join an external game (CSGO) The actual lobby isn't anything special but a scss styled <\div> tag with associated database entry which i want to appear for a certain amount of time.

**My question is:** How do i automatically destroy/remove the lobby <\div> tag along with the database entry after certain amount of time since its creation?

One of the options i found out is setting a cron task with whenever gem, but to my limited understanding it would work only in certain intervals and not certain time since lobby's creation.

Comment: You could run that task every minute. Is this not accurate enough?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would like to integrate ajax and have them appear and disappear in real time (in the future). That's why i'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delayed_job` gem. After installing delayed_job gem do the following:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_create :set_delete_timer

    # register the timer
    def set_delete_timer
      delay(:run_at => your_delete_time).expire
    end

    def expire
       delete_your_things_here  
    end

end
```